# Не работает камера

Tags: android, android-camera

Уже второй день не могу подружиться с камерой. Все статьи перечитал, все варианты перепробовал, и всё равно не работает.

Код, к которому я пришёл:

```
private static void takePic(){
    camera = Camera.open();
    photo = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    tphoto = new File(photo, "test.jpg");
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> allSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = allSizes.get(0); // get top size
    for (int i = 0; i < allSizes.size(); i++) {
        if (allSizes.get(i).width > size.width)
            size = allSizes.get(i);
    }
    parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    surfaceHolder = MainActivity.camera.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                        Log.i("CAMERA", "SAVE");
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tphoto);
                            try {
                                fos.write(bytes);
                                fos.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                MainActivity.errors++;
                                Panel.setErrors(MainActivity.errors);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            camera.release();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            MainActivity.errors++;
                            Panel.setErrors(MainActivity.errors);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                MainActivity.errors++;
                Panel.setErrors(MainActivity.errors);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}
    });
}
```

Ошибка:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed

Тестирую на Samsung Galaxy S4

Answer (score 0):

Пермишена очевидно нет. Если API level современный, то пермишен надо запрашивать в рантайме.

[RTFM](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Использую android 5.0.3. А RTFM с 6.0